# Finding curavature and torsion of a curve in terms of its Bishop frame

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

Suppose we are given a regular, naturally parametrized curve $\gamma :I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, how does one then compute the curvature and torsion of $\gamma$ in terms of the entries of the Bishop frame, which is given by
$$t \rightarrow  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & k_1^b(t) & k_2^b(t)\\
    -k_1^b(t) & 0 & 0 \\
    -k_2^b(t) & 0 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix}$$
I'm simply confused about the construction of the Bishop frame. In terms of the Frenet $(T,N,B)$ frame I know the Bishop frame is given by $f_1=T$, $f_2=\cos(\theta(t))\cdot N - \sin(\theta(t))\cdot B$, and $f_3=\sin(\theta(t))\cdot N+ \cos(\theta(t))\cdot B$, where $\theta '(t)=\tau(t) $. It appears to be straightforward but I seem to be messing up the calculations.

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Also, how "unique" is the Bishop frame of a regular curve? I think this also has been confusing me.

Comment: It's not unique. You can certainly rotate the frame by a constant angle along the curve. Perhaps the results of Exercise 11 on p. 33 of my differential geometry text (linked in my profile) will help.

Comment: Thank you very much. They certainly did :)